# Food fat content

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, fat, nutrition-information, cholesterol

While looking at 50g cashew fat content on [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%20cashews):

[image]

I see `total fat = 35g` and `saturated fat = 6g`, `no transfat`.

What else is counting as fat, I mean `35g - 6g = 29g`, what's that `29g`?

And an additional question, would you like to suggest an alternative to Wolfram? It was the 1st website of this kind I found, that's why I'm using it.

Answer (score 3):

Unsaturated fats, including monounsaturated and polyunsaturated fat, are additional types of fat that are often not individually listed on nutrition labels. They made up the remaining 29g.

Comment: And the unsaturated fats are the ones we want, right? So the close to zero that saturated fat number is the better, isn't?

Comment: That is correct.